# HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available, not displaying my webpage

Tags: mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I'm following the tutorial of Gerry devstory, creating a miniaml spring mvc jpa hibernate and mysql project, from March 3, 2014.

I think I've got most of the code right, but for some reason I can't figure out why it won't display.

Here's my code:

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>All Persons</h1>
<c:forEach var="p" items="${persons}">
    Id: ${p.id} Name: ${p.name}<br/>
</c:forEach>
<h1>Add New</h1>

<form method="post" action="addPerson">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <button>Add</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.java

```
package people;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personSvc;

    /**
     * Requests to http://localhost:8080/hello will be mapped here.
     * Everytime invoked, we pass list of all persons to view
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAll(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("persons", personSvc.getAll());
        return "home";
    }

    /**
     * POST requests to http://localhost:8080/hello/addPerson goes here.
     * The new person data is passed from HTML from and bound into the
     * Person object.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
        personSvc.add(person);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

PersonService.java

```
package people;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class PersonService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<Person> getAll() {
        List<Person> result = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class).getResultList();
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void add(Person p) {
        em.persist(p);
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package people;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;   
    /* getters & setters */
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence         
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"
                      value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-    
        3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Enable annotation-based Spring MVC controllers (eg: @Controller annotation) -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="hello"/>
    <!-- Resolve view name into jsp file located on /WEB-INF -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- MySQL Datasource with Commons DBCP connection pooling -->
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person"/>
        <property name="username" value="diana"/>
        <property name="password" value="nana88"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable @Transactional annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-
        app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    
        instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Everything Else -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>people</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

This is an image of the basic file structure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7eqzaak25cj8tac/Capture.PNG

This is the output file after I run it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzavkpm8blypd0g/image.png

Comment: Just dumping code will result many downvotes.  Better reduce your problem to a minimum and ask a specific question

Comment: You'll need to format the code better if you want people to be able to understand the problem

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have all spring managed beans in `people` package, but in spring configuration file(`spring-context.xml`) component-scan you have given `hello`,

so change from:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="hello" />
```

To:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="people" />
```

Also make sure you have **home.jsp** inside **${project_root}/WEB-INF/**

Answer (score 0):

3 obvious problems are:

- The home.jsp file should not be in the WEB-INF folder. Put it at the same level in the webapp folder.
- In your web.xml, your servlet url-pattern should be /*, not /.
- There is no indication in web.xml what the home page is for the application.